# Redirection after form submit only happens upon refresh

Tags: php, forms, redirect, modx

There are a few similar threads, but not one that addresses this case as far as I can tell.

I want to redirect a user to another page if a form submission is successful and valid. I'm using Modx, but you should be able to figure out the logic of the following code even if you don't use it. Basically it's just checking if something returns as true, and if so it redirects the page. Thing is, it doesn't work when the form is first submitted, but if the page is refreshed and the data sent again it works. Any ideas why?

```
if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['service']))
{
  $wlpe = new WebLoginPE($wlpe_lang);
  if($wlpe->TriggerLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) == true){
     $url = $modx->makeUrl('193', "", "", "full");
     $modx->sendRedirect($url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding additional code/file details would be useful.

Comment: Try placing the $url and $modx lines BEFORE the if(count...  line.  If you get the redirect, the problem is your logic, if not it is the modx code.

Comment: Is this snippet set to uncached? Ie. `[[!snippetName]]`